# lsalogonuser does not return token

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

lsalogonuser does not return a token, even though the return is success and event viewer shows the user to be logged in

The code matches many examples I found on the internet.
Some of the parameters are tricky involving careful pointer manipulation to ensure contiguous data.
But I think all of that is probably ok, since I get a zero return code indicating success and the event viewer shows the user logged in.
I have tried many variations of logon type. Some work and some don't. But I never get a non zero pointer for the token even for the ones that work

One point of doubt was the kerb_logon_submit_type enum
At least one microsoft site makes no mention of the non linear values.
But I found the code below and indeed 12 seems to work for the s4u type
(apart from non giving me a token)

I am grateful for any ideas

```
enum KERB_LOGON_SUBMIT_TYPE {
    KerbInteractiveLogon = 2,
    KerbSmartCardLogon = 6,
    KerbWorkstationUnlockLogon = 7,
    KerbSmartCardUnlockLogon = 8,
    KerbProxyLogon = 9,
    KerbTicketLogon = 10,
    KerbTicketUnlockLogon = 11,
    KerbS4ULogon = 12,
    KerbCertificateLogon = 13,
    KerbCertificateS4ULogon = 14,
    KerbCertificateUnlockLogon = 15,
}

[DllImport("secur32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern uint LsaLogonUser(
  [In] IntPtr LsaHandle,
  [In] ref LSA_STRING OriginName,
  [In] SECURITY_LOGON_TYPE LogonType,
  [In] uint AuthenticationPackage,
  [In] IntPtr AuthenticationInformation,
  [In] uint AuthenticationInformationLength,
  [In] IntPtr ptoken_groups,
  [In] ref TOKEN_SOURCE SourceContext,
  [Out] out IntPtr ProfileBuffer,
  [Out] out uint ProfileBufferLength,
  [Out] out LUID LogonId,
  [Out] out IntPtr Token,
  [Out] out QUOTA_LIMITS Quotas,
  [Out] out uint SubStatus
  );

 uint ntstatus = LsaLogonUser(lsahandle, ref origin_name, SECURITY_LOGON_TYPE.Network,
      authentication_package, auth_info, auth_info_length,
      IntPtr.Zero,
      ref token_source,
    out ProfileBuffer,
    out ProfileBufferLength,
    out LogonId,
    out Token,
    out quota_limits,
    out SubStatus);
```

After the call the pointer to the token is always 0, even if the call "succeeded" in the sense that the user was logged in and it returned zero meaning success

Comment: You'd better have a complete example that can be run to attempt to reproduce what you see. Other than that, have you seen [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winsdk/2015/08/28/logon-as-a-user-without-a-password/)? From that article: `... how can you programmatically generate an S4U token? ... WindowsIdentity s4u = new WindowsIdentity("user@domain"); ...
You'll see that this code is much easier than calling LsaLogonUser()....`

Comment: Does this have `SeTcbPrivilege` permissions? Anyway, here is a [sample](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0f1c411b-996c-4a00-87bc-155f3a79feb3/inconsistent-behavior-of-lsalogonuser-windows-system-call?forum=vcgeneral) with `KerbS4ULogon` could help.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I do know about creating a token via windowsidentity, but this is some code I was asked to make work. I am not sure of the utlimate objectives. Perhaps they are going to do some custom authentication which of course they could not do with  the new windowsidentitymethod. Regarding privileges, I am never sure if they need manually enabling or not (for some functions it seems to be enough that they exist) but I have anyway ensured SeTcbPrivilege was enabled.

Comment: I have noticed in some unrelated work that pinvoke.net sometimes does not match with current MS documentation (see DOCINFOW) so I will recheck all the declarations. Though I would be surprised if I had some declaration wrong and it still works as well as it does. I have come across just one other reference to the same problem on the Internet. This function seems to work for everyone once they get the arguments sorted. So I must be doing something wrong. Or there is some strange permission config in the domain I am using

Comment: Drake Wu thanks for the link. I believe that is one of the many examples I have looked at to try to spot a flaw in my code. It looks like you work for MS? Are there any official support channels for problems such as this? Of course, I would expect to be charged, but that is not a problem

Comment: You may submit a feedback on [feedback site](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/feedback/issues) for microsoft docs, or sumbit it directly in feedback hub.

Comment: @user2849221 Any change you solved your problem? `LsaLogonUser` also doesn't return a token for me.

Comment: user555 I am afraid I never solved this problem